# I want a background for my entire plot created with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, backgrounds, draw

I'm using `pgfplots` to create some simple plots for my document. I want the entire thing to have a yellowish background. What I dit was this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis background/.style={fill=yellow!30},
    axis lines=middle,
    every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=west},
    every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=south},
    xlabel={$x$},
    xtick=\empty,
    ylabel={$y$},
    ytick=\empty,
    ]
    \addplot [red,thick] plot {\x^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives me the following

[image: Picture as described in this question]

The yellow background stops where the axes stop. This does not really look like a proper background to me. I want the yellow square to be slightly bigger on all sides. Also, the yellow square should also be behind the x and y at least.

To get an idea of what I want, this is the syle I'm trying to mimic:

[image: Example of what I'm trying to create]

How can I get a better background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=west},
    every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=south},
    xlabel={$x$},
    xtick=\empty,
    ylabel={$y$},
    ytick=\empty,
    ]
    \addplot [red,thick] plot {\x^2};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \draw[fill=yellow!20,blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5,shadow xshift=-1mm},fill=yellow!30] 
    ([xshift=-3mm,yshift=-3mm]current axis.south west) rectangle 
    ([xshift=5mm,yshift=5mm]current axis.north east);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
%    axis background/.style={fill=yellow!30},
    axis lines=middle,
    every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=west},
    every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=south},
    xlabel={$x$},
    xtick=\empty,
    ylabel={$y$},
    ytick=\empty,
    ]
    \addplot [red,thick] plot {\x^2};
    \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \draw[blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5,shadow xshift=-1mm},fill=yellow!30] \pgfextra{\pgfplotspathaxisoutline};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```